# Return information from a get request with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Folks, i think my question is simple and stupid... but please, be gentle.

There is any way to return information from a get request with javascript? I wanna save the information of utmr from google analytics into a variable.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ND370.jpg

(sorry, for the bad english ;) )

Comment: Sure you can do this.
Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values

Answer (score 0):

[HTTP GET request in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247483/http-get-request-in-javascript)

```
function httpGet(theUrl)
{
var xmlHttp = null;

xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl, false );
xmlHttp.send( null );
return xmlHttp.responseText;
}
```